# Tying an Array of worksheets to a specific workbook

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, macros

The goal of my macro is from a large set of data, divide the data into separate workbooks for each product. After I paste only the specific data into the file, I want to copy 5 separate worksheets from the workbook with all of the data, each worksheet with a pivot table on them, set the data on the pivot table to the data on the spread sheet that I copied over previously. Then refresh the pivot tables.

My biggest question is how to I name an array of worksheets to a work book

```
Dim cell As Range, DataRng As Range
Dim curPath As String, curWB As String, newWB
Dim ArrayCM As Variant
Dim InxW As Long
Dim xTable As PivotTable

curPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
curWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'Array of worksheets to be copied over for Company Manger
Set ArrayCM = curWB.Sheets(Array("CM YTD", "CM MTD", "CM Refurb", "TBM Local", "PSM")) 
--This Gives me an error
```

Because I'm going to creating several workbooks, I want to define my array to copy over from the master file to the new file. Help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are confusing a ***String*** and a ***Workbook*** object.  `Set ArrayCM = Activeworkbook.Sheets(Array("CM YTD", "CM MTD", "CM Refurb", "TBM Local", "PSM"))`

Comment: `Workbooks(curWB)` not just `curWB`

Comment: I've tried both of these and neither worked. I want define the "Parent Workbook" so that I can copy worksheets to the children workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a worksheet type var as an array, redim it and assign each element within the array to a [Worksheet Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx).

```
Sub manyWSs()
    Dim w As Long
    Dim cwb As Workbook
    Dim wss() As Worksheet

    Set cwb = ThisWorkbook

    With cwb.Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3", "Sheet5"))
        ReDim wss(1 To .Count)
        For w = 1 To .Count
            Debug.Print .Item(w).Name
            Set wss(w) = .Item(w)
        Next w
    End With

    For w = LBound(wss) To UBound(wss)
        Debug.Print wss(w).Cells(1, 1).Address(0, 0, external:=True)
    Next w
End Sub
```

The `Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3", "Sheet5"))` is not a true [Worksheets collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224508(v=office.11).aspx) so `.Item(w)` is used to pick out the pieces. Once each piece has been `Set`, all the properties, methods and members of a single [Worksheet Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx) are available to each piece of the array with full parent [Workbook object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568.aspx) association.

Comment: It gives me an error every time I run `With cwb.Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3", "Sheet5"))` Only thing I changed was the name to the worksheets that I want in the array. Would I refer to this Array as "wss" correct?